# iPhone SDK: Optimize UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to flip my new ModalView with very high performance, but the new View has a lot of subviews so the performance of the Flip-Effect is very bad. Actually i do it with:

```
[controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:backSideController animated:YES];
```

I also tried it with

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.75;
[transition setType: @"flip"];
[transition setSubtype:@"fromRight"];

transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[transition setFillMode:@"extended"];

[[self.view layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


[self.view addSubview: backSideController.view];
[CATransaction commit];
```

With Core-Animation it works a little bit faster ... ware there further ways to opimize this task? e.g. Adding view when animation stops and just flipping a screenshot until animation stops?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing backsideController.view before you begin the animations.  This will cause backsideController's loadView and viewDidLoad to be called.  I'm guessing that this is your performance hit -- that all that loading & allocating is causing the animation to stutter.

You don't need anything fancy, you can do something like:

```
if (backsideController.view == nil)
    NSLog(@"Where's my view?!");
```

before your other code, above.

I don't believe that having many-many subviews causes performance problems on the flip; I'm pretty sure (without looking at your code or checking in instruments, which you should do!) that the problem is the time it takes to load and allocate the view components.

Also, I'd stick with `presentModalViewController`, if it does what you want.  Having all that extra code in your 2nd example -- unless it's needed for functionality -- is just maintenance headache.